# Get eBay buyer information by item id or transaction id

Tags: ebay-api, affiliate

I am an eBay affiliate. How can I get details of eBay user, who made purchases on eBay through my website. When I try using `GetItemTransaction` API call I get an error:

> This item cannot be accessed because the listing has been deleted, is
>   a Half.com listing, or you are not the seller.

Can anyone suggest me some alternative method to get that info ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited amount of information that eBay will share about purchases (really only how many sold). You will not be able to pull up any information on the individual user if you are not the seller of the item. In general, most of the Trading API calls require you to be part of the actual transaction (buyer or seller).

But, you can pull some useful information regarding items using the [GetMultipleItems Shopping API](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html).

Some of the info you can get from this is quantity available, quantity sold, and of course the price of the item and its picture.